# Let $A \subset X$ and $Y = (X-A) \cup \{A\}$ with $(X,\tau_x)$ a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset X$ and $Y = (X-A) \cup \{A\}$ with $(X,\tau_x)$ a topological space.

now define $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ by $\pi(x) = x$ if $x\notin A$ and $\pi(x) = \{A\}$ if $x\in A$ consider $Y$ with topology $\tau_y = \{V \subset Y, \pi^{-1}(V) \in \tau_x\}$

1) Show that if $F \subset X$ with $F$ closed and $F \cap A = \emptyset$ then $\pi(F)$ is closed in $Y$.
We have to show that $\pi(F)^c \in \tau_y$ or $(\pi^{-1}(\pi(F)))^c \in \tau_x$ using the fact that $F \cap A = \emptyset$ and the $\pi$ definition we have that $\pi$ is injective, so $(\pi^{-1}(\pi(F)))^c = F^c$ and the result follows.

2)Show that if $Y$ is Hausdorff space then then $A$ is closed in $X$
I was think to show that the only neighborhood $V_x = \{A\}$ that has $A$ as element and for any $y \in X - A$ implies that $V_x \cap V_y = \emptyset$. But i was unable to write that.

Thank any hint in both problems.

Comment: You probably mean $\pi(x)=A$ if $x\in A$, not $\pi(x)=\{A\}$. Note that $\{A\}$ is not a priori in $Y$.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the comment, but in the problem is $\pi(x) = \{A\}$. ops i forgot "\{"

Comment: But then $\pi$ is not a function defined on $X$ with values in $Y$. What is your source?

Comment: @Did Why is not a function? $x = y \Rightarrow \pi(x) \neq \pi(y)$? my source is a brazilian exam. heres the link http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~posgrad/NOVO/Matem%C3%A1tica/Mestrado/D2011.pdf.

Comment: @Did The problem is in the last page, question 2.

Comment: This is a misprint because, as already mentioned, the notation $\pi:X\to Y$ means that $\pi(x)\in Y$ for every $x\in X$. But $\{A\}\notin Y$ hence, to specify that $\pi(x)=\{A\}$ for some $x\in X$ is absurd. On the other hand, $\pi(x)=A$ would be correct (and probably what is meant) since $A\in Y$.

Comment: @Did thank you very much !! this kind of thing make u loose points .. but when is the teacher... "aaa ,  it's obvious"...

Comment: You are welcome. Yes this specific misprint at this specific place is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t say that $\pi$ is injective: it’s injective if and only if $A$ is a one-point set. What *is* true is that $\pi\upharpoonright X\setminus A$, the restriction of $f$ to $X\setminus A$, is injective. We’ll use this, but not yet. In order to show that $\pi[F]$ is closed in $Y$, you must, as you said, show that $Y\setminus\pi[F]$ is open in $Y$. By the definition of $\pi$ this means showing that $\pi^{-1}\big[Y\setminus\pi[F]\big]$ is open in $X$.

Since $F\cap A=\varnothing$, $A\notin\pi[F]$, and therefore $A\in Y\setminus\pi[F]$. Thus, $A\subseteq\pi^{-1}\big[Y\setminus\pi[F]\big]$. What else is in $\pi^{-1}\big[Y\setminus\pi[F]\big]$? If $x\in X\setminus A$, then $\pi(x)=x$, so $x\in\pi^{-1}\big[Y\setminus\pi[F]\big]$ if and only if $x\in Y\setminus\pi[F]$. And $F\cap A=\varnothing$, so $\pi[F]=F$, and $x\in\pi^{-1}\big[Y\setminus\pi[F]\big]$ if and only if $x\in Y\setminus F$. Thus,

$$\pi^{-1}\big[Y\setminus\pi[F]\big]=A\cup\{x\in X\setminus A:x\notin F\}=X\setminus F\;,$$

which is indeed open in $X$.

For the second problem use the fact that $\pi$ is defined in a way that makes it continuous, so that if $F$ is a closed subset of $Y$, then $\pi^{-1}[F]$ is closed in $X$. Then use the hypothesis that $Y$ is Hausdorff to show that the singleton set $\{A\}$ is a closed set in $Y$.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian M . Scott, Your answer is very clear.

Comment: @Francisco: You're very welcome.

Comment: The singleton $\{\{A\}\}$ is not, in general, a subset of $Y$.

Comment: No, $\{A\}$ is not an element of $Y$ in general (it probably never is, but I did not check and this is not the point of my comment). The question reads $Y = (X-A) \cup \{A\}$. Assume for example that $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and that $A=\{0,1\}$, then $X-A=\{2\}$ (a singleton) and $\{A\}$ is a singleton hence $Y$ is the two-points set whose elements are $2$ and $A=\{0,1\}$. Clearly, none of these is $\{A\}$.

Comment: @Did: Indeed, I misread the definition as a slightly different one that I’ve also seen used in this setting. I expect that I’d have noticed this the first time had your comment been a bit more helpful — e.g., ‘$Y$ is $(X\setminus A)\cup\{A\}$, not $(X\setminus A)\cup\{\{A\}\}$’.

Comment: "had your comment been a bit more helpfu" The *chutzpah*...

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question in 1). But for 2), hint:  It's obvious that $\pi$ is continuous (Why?). Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, $\{A\}$ is closed. Thus $A=\pi^{-1}(\{A\})$ is cloded in $X$.